# How can I display my formatted JSON data horizontally, similar to an ecommerce site?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am working with an API to request specific types of purses from a retailer's website.  I then formatted the JSON data so that the purse image and purse name is displayed.  However, it is displayed vertically, one purse per row.  I would like to display these items next to each other as you see in ecommerce sites.  How would I do that/  Below is my code.  I did not include my API key though for privacy purposes.  Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //make HTTP request
        $.get("http://api.vsapi01.com/search/by-url?apikey=[insert key here]0&url=https://product-images4.therealreal.com/BAL31068_2_product.jpg&index=real-bags ", function(data){
               
          data['images'].forEach(function(image,index,images) { 
            var bagName = image.title;
           
            var clickURL = image.pageUrl;
            var pictureURL = image.imageUrl;
     var image = "<img src=\""+pictureURL+"\"/>";
            var clickableImage = "<a href=\"" + clickURL + "\">" + image + "</a>";
            var wholeImage = "<div>"  + clickableImage + "<br>" + bagName + "<br> " + "<div>";                      
            $( ".display" ).append(wholeImage);
            });
        });
     });
```

```html
<div class="display"></div>
```

Comment: Does `.display` have it's `display` property set to `inline-block` in your CSS? Also, please show your CSS.

Comment: my CSS was simply:  .display{float:left;}  But in any case, the inline-block worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Sam mentioned in his comment, the `display` property of `.display` should be set to `inline-block`:

```
.display {
    display: inline-block
}
```

---

**Explanation**

This is because the `div` element, which is a block element by default, will always move to the next line after the last block. Setting the element to `inline-block` will keep all the properties of a block element, but will allow multiple blocks on the same line.

**Further Reading**

[CSS `Display` Property at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)